# Objectlistview how to change the text in the group header?

Tags: c#, listview, sum, objectlistview

I want to change the name of the group header but i cant find any solutions in the documentation or on google.

the text in the header should be a time which is summed up in the group.

this is how it should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> the text in the header should be a time which is summed up in the group.

No problem :)

```
olv.AboutToCreateGroups += delegate(object sender, CreateGroupsEventArgs args) {
    foreach (OLVGroup olvGroup in args.Groups) {
        int totalTime = 0;

        foreach (OLVListItem item in olvGroup.Items) {
            // change this block accordingly
             MyRowObjectType rowObject = item.RowObject as MyRowObjectType;
             totalTime += rowObject.MyNumericProperty;
            // change this block accordingly
        }

        olvGroup.Header += String.Format(" (Total time = {0})", totalTime);
    }
};
```

Comment: 1. what is delegate and where should i write this code down? cuz I found the event "Abouttocreategroups" but it´s actually not working there
2. And what is MyRowObjectType? (which using should I use)?

Comment: `AboutToCreateGroups` is an ObjectListView event and is called before the groups are displayed. So you can actually make changes there to the groups that will directly reflect on the OLV. MyRowObjectType was just a placeholder for the underlying type of object that you use to populate the OLV. Access its `Zeit` property there add add them up.