# Possible to put text/data on groupheader under columns in ObjectListView?

Tags: c#, winforms, grouping, objectlistview

I want to place text / data that sums, averages or whatever operation I would like on a group header under a column? I cannot find any documentation online or examples which do this with ObjectListView?

Is it possible at all? If not what alternatives do I have to to achieve this? Quite vital piece for the app I am building.

Please see this image as an example of what I mean.
[image: Example]

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32780785/1790864

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Objectlistview how to change the text in the group header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32779907/objectlistview-how-to-change-the-text-in-the-group-header)

Comment: @Rev1.0 
Not quite. In your example, that changes the group header name. As you can see in the pictured example the text for the group appear under the relevant column. Any idea how that can happen?

Comment: Essentially you want to align the values to the respective column, I got that. I do not think there is a straightforward way to do that and you will have to touch the core functionality of OLV. But you probably should ask yourself if you really need that. Maybe you could just properly format the header text and be done. Like `"W (Total size: 21.08 MB / Avg. rating: 45)`.

Comment: See this post from the Author of the control, he mentions the limitations.  https://sourceforge.net/p/objectlistview/discussion/812922/thread/7f2bc2f4/